# .Net String Format Display Currency Value In Millions

Tags: .net, silverlight, string-formatting

I am trying to write a string format which takes currency numbers in the range of millions, for example 275983.35 and then display this as 2.7. This is for use as scaling numbers on a legend.

The control I am using requires string formats like this `{}{0:my string format}`

I have managed to get the display to show 2.7 by using `{}{0:0,,.0}` but this does not display the currency symbol. How can I get the currency symbol to show without hard coding a single currency symbol in, like so: `{}{0;$0,,.0}`.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11531/Money-DataType - its actually a great DataType, I've had a lot of success with it!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to divide the number by 1,000,000 and then display that using standard currency formatting. This will give you the localisation of the currency - but **not** and indication that this was millions of dollars/pounds/euros.

A better solution will be to write a custom converter that will do the division by a million select the correct currency symbol and then append a "m" (or whatever symbol you decide) to indicate that this is millions.

```
public class MillionsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value / 1000000M).ToString("C2") + " m";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then in XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Converters:MillionsConverter  x:Key="MillionsConverter " />
</ResourceDictionary>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource MillionsConverter}" />
```

This will output:

> $2.7m

Obviously, you'll need to tweak the converter to get the exact format you want.